# Facebook with FlashFacebook Api - Infinite Session with different users using same app, is it possible?

Tags: flash, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, infinite

Here is my situation, everytime a user gets a new highscore, i wanna send a facebook message into my game account, and i've managed to do that with infinite session, i've stored the session data with the attributes of my account and always connects directly to my profile and posts it.

Now imagine that i want to do the same thing, but with another profile, is it possible to user the same application? Any ideas how would i identify the different accounts before logging in?

Or do i have to have different facebook programs doing the same things for different account?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Session key was used in old REST API, access token is used in new OAuth and Graph API.
i prefer token, my example is:
User Michael can only retrieve one token for FarmVille(game application) on the same time.
FarmVille(game application) only have one api key/secret key to assigned to do it.

But, Michael can own 2 or more different token at the same time,such as FarmVille and Farmvillage at the same time, but it's not interchangeable.

If you have two account named Michael and David, so you can get two token for same apps, like FarmVille, but it's also not interchangeable.

**For correction, "User Michael can only retrieve one token for FarmVille(game application) on the same time" is wrong, User Michael can retrieve more than one token on the same apps, if the permissions is DIFFERENT. However it's still not absolute true yet, that's a moment you can hold multiple tokens with same permission and same apps via https://www.facebook.com/desktop/notifier/transfer.php?__a=1**